# Why am I getting null for the date when I create a Todo entity?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

What is wrong with my to-do application? I want the user to be able to add a todo and have it be saved in my MySQL database with the time it was created, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

*I am new to learning Springboot and would appreciate any suggestions or advice.*

**Todo Entity:**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;


@Entity(name = "Todo")
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "todos")
public class Todo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name="target_date")
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Date targetDate;

    public Todo(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Date getTargetDate() {
        return targetDate;
    }

    public void setTargetDate(Date targetDate) {
        this.targetDate = targetDate;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Todo{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", description='" + description + '\'' +
                ", targetDate=" + targetDate +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**Adding a Todo with Spring Data JPA**

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import java.util.List;

@Repository
@Component
public interface TodoRepository extends JpaRepository<Todo, Integer> {

    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "INSERT INTO todos (description) VALUES (:description)", nativeQuery=true)
    @Transactional
    void addTodo(@Param("description") String description);

}
```

**TodoController**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/todos")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TodoController {

    @Autowired
    private ITodoService todoService;

    @PostMapping(value = "/add-todo")
    public String addTodo(@RequestParam String description) {
        Todo todo = new Todo();
        todo.setDescription(description);
        todoService.addTodo(todo);

        return todo.toString();
    }
```

after getting a post request, the target_date is getting NULL in MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you can solve it by using `persist()`:

```
@Autowired EntityManager entityManager;

@PostMapping(value = "/add-todo")
    public String addTodo(@RequestParam String description) {
        Todo todo = new Todo();
        todo.setDescription(description);
        entityManager.persist(todo);

        return todo.toString();
    }
```

Comment: I think the problem here is that you're using nativeQuery to create an entity, let's try it that way

Comment: I get this error:
"No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'persist' call"

Comment: You can add `@Transactional` annotation just above `@PostMapping` to solve it, it's better to move this logic to service layer, but anyway

Comment: Thank you for your help. How can I move this to the service layer?

Comment: Move @Autowired EntityManager entityManager into your TodoService; Create `addTodo(String description)` also here and add @Transactional annotation to it, copy paste `Todo todo = new Todo(); todo.setDescription(description); entityManager.persist(todo);` to the addTodo() method body and that's it :)